# Force Emacs to use tabs in php mode

Tags: php, emacs, indentation

I want Emacs to use tabs instead of spaces in php mode.
I tried the putting the following code

```lisp
;; Turn on tabs
(setq indent-tabs-mode t)
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)

;; Bind the TAB key
(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'self-insert-command)

;; Set the tab width
(setq default-tab-width 4)
(setq tab-width 4)
(setq c-basic-indent 4)
```

in my .emacs. Then I open a php-mode buffer and press `<C-q><Tab>` but Emacs still inserts 4 spaces instead of a tab. I've spent a lot of time searching for this. The code above is just one of the solutions that didn't work.
What am I missing here?

(I know many consider tabs evil, but in the company I work it's a standard, so using space indentation is not an option for me while I'm on work)

Comment: If `C-q TAB` inserts 4 spaces, then there's a problem somewhere.  Are you sure about that?  Are you sure you're not fooled by some other feature, such as the fact that backspace might convert the TAB back into 4 spaces just before deleting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```el
(add-hook 'php-mode-hook 'my-php-mode-hook)
(defun my-php-mode-hook ()
  (setq indent-tabs-mode t)
  (let ((my-tab-width 4))
    (setq tab-width my-tab-width)
    (setq c-basic-indent my-tab-width)
    (set (make-local-variable 'tab-stop-list)
         (number-sequence my-tab-width 200 my-tab-width))))
```

Setting the tab-stop-list may or may not be redundant here, as I'm not whether it ever gets used in php-mode. There's no harm in setting it, however.

Note that `indent-tabs-mode`, `tab-width`, and `c-basic-indent` are all automatic buffer-local variables. When you use `C-h v` to ask Emacs about them, it will tell you this is the case. Because of this, the way you were using `setq` in your original code would not have any effect on other buffers. The correct way to change the default value for this kind of variable is to use `setq-default`. The `default-tab-width` variable is obsolete; such variables have been deprecated in favour of using `setq-default` with the normal variable name.

The mode hook approach in my code sets the buffer-local values in the context of the php-mode buffer you are editing, so with that approach you don't need to mess with the default values if you don't want to.

In your case you may wish to some defaults anyway, especially if you will be editing more than just PHP code.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is very clear. I got that code googling around, I didn't know about the default-tab-width being obsolete. But your code doesn't seem to work neither. I got it working in most other modes, but in php it seems to be hardcoded inside the php-mode.el

Comment: I suspect there is some conflicting configuration. If you start `emacs -Q`, then copy my code into the `*scratch*` buffer and `M-x eval-buffer`, then manually `M-x load-file` your `php-mode.el` file and open a php file for editing, do you still have the same problem? Which version of Emacs and which php-mode are you using? If you're not already, I would suggest trying https://github.com/ejmr/php-mode which is actively developed.

Comment: I already removed all my emacs config and tried doing as you said using the php-mode from the github. But the problem persists.
I'm using the version Emacs 24.3.1 and the php-mode was nxhtml-2.08-100425

Answer (score 1):

I found a simpler way of achieving this. Do `M-x` > `customize-variable` > `php-mode-coding-style` and change it to `Wordpress`.

Comment: Is this a minor mode for `php-mode`? If so, which version do you use? I can't find this `php-mode-coding-style` variable in my installation...

Comment: I reply to myself: it's actually a newer version of [`php-mode` from melpa](http://melpa.org/#/php-mode).

Answer (score 0):

How about a different approach? Insert the tabs when saving found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318553/getting-emacs-to-untabify-when-saving-certain-file-types-and-only-those-file-ty) SO question that does the reverse you can probably reverse engineer it to `tabify` instead of `untabify`

Comment: I took a quick look and it seems it works. I'll try to implement it later. Right now I'm at work. Thanks in advance

Comment: `tabify` should *definitely* convert spaces to tabs (provided there are `tab-width` consecutive spaces). Again, I have to suspect you have some other configuration which is conflicting with these attempted changes, and would suggest starting with `emacs -Q` and manually applying only the settings you wish to test, in order to ascertain whether they work under normal circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

FWIW, I think you're simply wasting your time: stop worrying about tabs vs spaces and just move on.

This said, if that's really what you want, you can try:

```
(add-hook 'php-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key [?\t] 'self-insert-command)))
```

Comment: Like I said in my question, my company has a standard for the code format. I wish I could use spaces but when I'm on work I need tabs. That's what keeping me from using Emacs at work.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it still enters 4 spaces instead of a tab